# Disabling formset form field

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, formset

I am trying to disable some formset form fields. But i couldn't achieve it.
I have below formset. If the status is Missing the related status field should be disabled. So that nobody can change it. If the status is Report the field will be enabled so that somebody can change it. the DB value of Missing is 1 and Report is 2.

[image]

I tried below code in the views.py but i get error.

> 'TypedChoiceField' object has no attribute 'value'

```
for form in formset:
    if form.fields["status"].value() == 1:
        form.fields["status"].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True
```

The status field in model is :

```
status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUSES, default=None, verbose_name=_("Status"))
```

Comment: Try doing `if form.instance.status == 1` instead. It might be better to disable the field in the form's `__init__` method instead of the view, but I can't tell because you've shown so little code.